# How tell Gradle where to look for javax.servlet?

Tags: java, gradle, servlets, build.gradle

I'm trying to make a servlet application with gradle as build system. The problem is that gradle cannot find javax.servlet, I'm getting this error:

```
Could not find javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0
```

I downloaded Tomcat9 from the official site and unpacked it to ~/opt/tomcat9. There is ~/opt/tomcat9/lib folder, where servlet-api.jar is located. I guess that jar file is what gradle looking for, but how do I specify the path to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We usually add the Servlet API as an compileOnly dependency to our projects. This way gradle will use the JAR for compiliing, but not include it in deployments. At deployment, your [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) will provide the Servlet API.

Add something like this to your dependencies declaration:

`compileOnly 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:9.0.37'`

Using the Jar from your local Tomcat would be theoretically possible, but I'd avoid non-metadata dependencies as it is usually simpler to have everything "in one place".

That said, adding a local directory that contains JARs to your build would look something like

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'path/to/tomcat/libs'
    }
}
```